# The SLXOLEDB.1 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm building a REST web service in WCF.

When I run the WCF project from Visual Studio, everything works fine. Calling the 'Post' method on a specific endpoint works just fine. But when I try to run the same web service from the IIS Manager, calling the same method on the same endpoint throws the exception = "The SLXOLEDB.1 provider is not registered on the local machine."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows :

Go to the 'Advanced Settings' for the application pool for your service and change the 'Identity' to 'LocalSystem'.